# SQL Reporting Services with SSL exclusively

Tags: ssl, ssrs

I know how to add an SSL cert to SSRS 2008. Is there a way to force SSRS to use SSL (port 443) exclusively? Right now it will respond to both encrypted and unencrypted requests.

IIS has the Require Secure Channel option. Does SSRS have the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding setting in SSRS seems to be SecureConnectionLevel=3 in RSReportServer.config (http://forums.asp.net/p/1299521/2767061.aspx; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx).

Another thing to try is to remove the http-addresses in Reporting Services Configuration Manager, under Web Service URL and Report Manager URL. But I have not tried this myself.